# how to load different html pages in a web view by clicking on options menu item?

Tags: android, android-menu

Please let me know where am i exactly going wrong. the code doesn't give any compile time errors but, in run time it gives a force shutdown error.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page1.html");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item1:

        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page1.html");
        return true;
    case R.id.item2:

        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page2.html");
        return true;
    case R.id.item3:

        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page3.html");
        return true;
    case R.id.item4:
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page4.html");
        return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

> The exception's stack trace is:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.sample.onOptionsItemSelected(suraj_resume.java:38) at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2205) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java‌​:748) at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143) at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:85‌​5) at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)

Comment: please add the exception you see in logcat

Comment: it gives a java.lang.NullPointerException and error on the loadurl line in the switch case statement.

Comment: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.sample.onOptionsItemSelected(suraj_resume.java:38)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2205)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:748)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)




`

Comment: at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

Comment: and what is the code you have in suraj_resume.java line 38 (suraj_resume.java:38) ?

Comment: its `wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page1.html");` not only this line but the line changes according to the options item i select. ie. if i select item 2 the error will be in the line that loads page 2. and so on for page 3 and 4.

Comment: hey thank u sir, for giving your precious time for solving my problem. but finally i got the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution of my problem by just creating new objects of the same web view in each case.the running code is as shown below.

---

`public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            WebView wv1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            wv1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/resume_page1.html");
            return true;
        case R.id.item2:
            WebView wv2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            wv2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/resume_page2.html");
            return true;
        case R.id.item3:
            WebView wv3 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            wv3.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/resume_page3.html");
            return true;
        case R.id.item4:
            WebView wv4 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            wv4.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/resume_page4.html");
            return true;`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
 wv.loadUrl(“javascript:changeLocation(‘” + url + “‘)”);
```

Also you should create a folder named "www" inside the assets folder to hold your files.

Further more your last `case` statement should look like this:

```
case R.id.item4:
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page4.html");
    return true;



    default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);}
    }
```

Comment: sorry but can i know the need of creating a "www" folder in my assets folder? as those pages are just an html pages i dont need to get it from internet or even connect to it. just to display them one by one on a click in options menu items.

Comment: i thought i remembered i had to create it when using a newer sdk version but that might not be true. anyhow it will be nicer but you don't need to follow. have you tried the code though? i also saw something else wrong with your code. see my edit of my answer please...

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NullPointerException`

you're not keeping the reference to the WebView.
Declare the WebView wv outside the onCreate, so that reference can be used by the menu item selected.